# Filter option "No accepted answer" filtered more than necessary

Tags: bug, filtering, custom-questions-list

If I search `wpf` questions with bounty and "No accepted answer", there are no results.

[image]

But if I uncheck "No accepted answer" and search again, there are two results, one question with no accepted answer:

[image]

So, there is an issue in the first search, it should return one question instead of nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really specific to questions with bounties. Apparently, the **"No accepted answer"** filter only returns questions with no *upvoted* or *accepted* answers (even for questions with no bounties). The heading on top of the dialog states that fact:

[image]

Perhaps, the checkbox text should read **"No accepted/upvoted answer"** if they don't plan to add more filters. Obviously, the better alternative would be to have two checkboxes; one filters out accepted answers only and the other filters out upvoted answers.

This was reported in an answer on Meta.SE last year and a staff member [replied in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement#comment1077885_330366) saying basically the same thing and mentioning that they will look into changing the wording of the checkbox text. Apparently, that wasn't pursued though.